# Laravel return response to endpoint from bootstrap/app.php file

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-apollo

I am connecting to database in app.php file. I want to send 404 response if database does not exists or if there is some error.

The code is as below.

```
$conn = new mysqli(env('DB_HOST'), env('DB_USERNAME'), env('DB_PASSWORD'), env('DB_DATABASE'));

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
  header('Content-type: application/json', TRUE, 404);
  echo json_encode([
    'status' => 'ERROR',
    'code' => 404,
    'errors' => [
      [
        'message' => 'Sorry, Something went wrong.',
      ],
    ],
  ]);
  exit;
}
```

This shows response in postman but does not show any response on frontend when request sent from browser. Shows network error failed to fetch.(Apollo graphql being used on frontend)

Comment: You probably want to check `DB::connection()->getPdo()` in some service provider to see if you can connect. `bootstrap/app.php` isnt a file you want to modify in most cases.

Comment: Does it show a 404 page in postman in case of any error?

Comment: If you cant connect to the db it will throw an exception? so why do you wanna do this custom?